# Python Speech to text and speech recognition

Tags: python, audio, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I am planning to create a code that can listen a recorded audio file and can identify the conversation between two or more people..i.e is there any way to find out what a particular individual said?

Is there a way if i can create text transcript using audio by person?Using python speech to text.

I don't know where to start. I am just creating this code for my knowledge.any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What you are looking for is `speaker diarization`. There are libraries like `kaldi`, `cmu sphnix`. You can look into these library.

Comment: These are python libraries?

Comment: Not python libraries. Python wrappers available to use.

Comment: Thanks a lot Narendra, Do you have any tutorial for the same?

Comment: http://jrmeyer.github.io/asr/2016/02/01/Kaldi-notes.html this is a great tutorial for Kaldi. If my comments are helpful you can give like the comment. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a way, see this tutorial.https://realpython.com/python-speech-recognition/